# InDesign "Data Source" - to simple IPad/Android app

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, pdf, adobe-indesign

Ok,
I will not get full answer to this question, but perhaps somebody can give me a few tips, or tell me if it is feasable at all. The current situation is:

A printed out document created from a InDesign file.
No great structure in the data beside the visual markup.
The document is used as a GUIDE/CHECKLIST style.

So kind of "read some stuff" - "if yes page 20" - "if no page 34"
A little bit like these early TXT only adventures.

The client now want to "put this on a tablet" - the obvious approach is to take all the data, format it in some nice XML, write an app to render the data and provide the extra features.

Now, on the other hand, they are already close to their final product, a simple PDF rendering of the document looks nice on a tablet. There are some features missing, however, like "navigate back links" (you click, go to page 23, click there on "back" and are where you started).

I though I could do this with JS in PDF, but this does not work on Android. He just ignores the javascript (calculator example).

So now, before suggesting to implement your own solution, I am looking for something still close to the source. E.g. InDesign PLUS CODE.

I hope you get my drift. Perhaps another example: What you cant do with a simple Word Dokument, you do with VBA inside word.

What I cant do with a simple PDF I do with ??? + ???? on IPad/Android (we would not need both versions, one is enough, its a closed system, we control the device and the source file. Perfect for a standalone app, but overkill for step 1, I think).

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You should consider going with iBooks for this. The format works really well with tools like In Design and you can use HTML5 tools to embed links, navigation, video, etc. You don't go the App Store route, but instead go with the iBookStore which can give just as good of a revenue option. The new iBooks Author will be a great tool, but even older tutorials will still work. Here is [a good starting place](http://www.eisforbook.com/2011/02/gaggle-of-links-about-making-ibooks.html)

Comment: Does IBooks support simple scripting, like the "conditional backlinks"?

Comment: If you mean links to other parts of the book that have logic associated to them the answer is yes.

Comment: Yeah, we need a feature that is a "link back to last page" - so if I am on page 12, there might be a link to page 27, and on page 27 the link "back to intro" must lead to 12. If I would have come from 16, it must lead back to 16. Should be a piece of cake with javascript.